# Issue with emmeans code after nb.glm that worked fine previously

Tags: compare, emmeans

I am having the following issue when I try to do a pairwise comparison after running nb.glm.

```
> marginal = emmeans(CD, ~Trt) ## For pairwise comparison after glm.nb (emmeans pkg req)##
```

Error in ref_grid(object, ...) : 
  Can't handle an object of class  “numeric”

It was working fine until last week.

Can someone help me out?
TIA

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear. `CD` is not a model object. Perhaps you overwrote it. Really-fit your model and go from there.

Comment: Oops, auto-incorrect strikes again. I meant re-fit your model...

Comment: Tried to re-fit the model but getting the same error

Comment: What do you get if you do `summary(CD)`?

Comment: Values for CD; Min. 1st Q. median. mean. 3rd Q. Max.

Comment: Well then, `CD` is a vector of numbers. It is not a negative binomial model object. When you run `glm.nb`, you have to save that result under a name, e.g., `mymodel = nb.glm(...)`. Then `emmeans(mymodel, ...)`